# How to remove item at the top of List View in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I have List View and I have inside each item in the list a button called "Delete item". When I press that button inside each item I want to delete only that item from the list.

But it does not delete item, it just display Toast message that I have specified.

How I can solve this?

This is the code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
listItems = buildVCsFromAPI(context);

return Container(
  child: ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
          _buildListItem(context, listItems[index], index),
      itemCount: listItems.length,
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
);
}

Widget _buildListItem(
  BuildContext context, _VerifiableCredentialListItem cert, int index) {
return GestureDetector(
  child: AnimatedAlign(
    curve: Curves.ease,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    heightFactor: selectedPosition == index ? factorMax : factorMin,
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)), //here
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                offset: Offset(0, -1),
                blurRadius: 10.0)
          ]),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          HeadingRow(title: cert.fullTitle, appIcon: cert.appIcon),
          displayListItem(index, selectedPosition, cert)
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  }

  Column displayListItem(
  int index, int selectedIndex, _VerifiableCredentialListItem cert) {
CredentialListGroupType groupType = cert.groupType;
return Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: UIConstants.s2,
    ),
    buildAnotherWidget(),
    SizedBox(
      height: UIConstants.s3,
    ),
    buildDeleteAndExportButtons(),
  ],
);
}

Column buildDeleteAndExportButtons() {
return Column(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: UIConstants.s1, horizontal: UIConstants.s2),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: BlueButtonWithIcon(
              text: 'Delete item',
              icon: 'assets/icons/delete-icon.svg',
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  AppToaster.pop(ToasterType.info, "Delete");
                  listItems.removeAt(0);
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: UIConstants.s1),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: BlueButtonWithIcon(
              text: 'Export',
              icon: 'assets/icons/export.svg',
              onPressed: null,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(height: UIConstants.s1)
  ],
);
}
```

Comment: Where have you declared `listItems` ?

Comment: I have edited code. Can you take look?

Answer (score 1):

Calling setState doesn't mean that flutter would actually full repaint the screen it means that it will check your widget tree with the last rendered widget tree and it will paint only the differences and it first compares widgets type and then widget keys to find that there is a difference between the current widget and the previous one and because of this when you remove an item from your list of items flutter checks your returned widgets to the currently rendered widget it doesn't found any difference and it won't repaint the screen and continues showing the last render

So for you to tell the flutter that one of the items in the listView is changed you could assign a uniqueKey key for each list item widget note that for this topic your keys should be unique to the data of that widget otherwise you will face performance issues because if your widget key is changed without any change in the representation of that widget in next time that builds method is called which could happen frequently flutter compares widgets key with the previous widgets key which is rendered to the screen and exist on the render tree and it founds that the keys are different and it repaints that widget which is a redundant operation because your widgets UI and representation are the same

For example, assign a unique id base on the index or content of your data to each data model in the listItems and use that to create a ValueKey() for the widget that is represented by that data

here is a working example of the list which when you click on the list item first list item will be removed

[image: Demo of a list with removable items in flutter]

```
class ListItemDataModel {
  final String id;
  final Color color;

  ListItemDataModel(this.id, this.color);
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<ListItemDataModel> items = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    items = [
      ListItemDataModel("A", Colors.red),
      ListItemDataModel("B", Colors.amber),
      ListItemDataModel("C", Colors.green),
      ListItemDataModel("D", Colors.lightBlueAccent),
      ListItemDataModel("E", Colors.pink),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              key: ValueKey(items[index].id),
              //Tap to Remove first item from list
              onTap: () {
                items.removeAt(0);
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 60,
                color: items[index].color,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                      "This is a unique item with id = ${items[index].id}"),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: items.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried with keys,  but I could not make it to work. To which widget I should add Key?

Comment: to the first level widget, i will update my answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

So,

We don't have acces to the code above.. so.. where does listItems came from?
Maybe you are retrieving the value of listItems after the init state? if so it's normal that you are retrieving always the same result..

What you should do is the following:

- get listItems value from params, global vars, databse ecc
- display the list
- when you delete a single item you should update the original list
- on state updated now the list will be loaded with updated values

If you delete an item from a list but the list is then reloaded in its original form your updates will be lost

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have updated code to show where I am getting listItems. It is from the API call and I do some mapping to filter values.